# Invert image captured from ImageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

I have an image (outlined in red) displaying the result of [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer) called on a canvas.  I want to invert the colors such that the tiny resulting image is white text on a black background.  I've tried various methods from stackoverflow to invert the colors but each results in a blank result.  I'm fairly new to Swift and iOS development, whats the easiest way to invert the colors of that smaller result image?

```
      Button(action: {
        guard let image = ImageRenderer(content: canvas).uiImage else {
          // failed to render view as image
          return
        }
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        resultImage = Image(uiImage: image)
      }){
        Text("Analyze")
      }
```

[image: Image of simulator showing canvas view and smaller view of the image derived from the canvas drawing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

`ColorInvert` enables you to implement the features you want.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image("sample")
                .colorInvert()
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: When I create the image from the capture of the canvas in `Image(uiImage: resultImage)`, I'm using 'colorInvert()', but it's producing nothing but white.  If I remove the `colorInvert()` call I get the image of what was drawn on the canvas.

Comment: I think the reason why black is not produced is because the part that needs to be converted is transparent, not white.
White -> Black,
Black -> White,
Clear -> Nothing?.

Can I temporarily put any color on the screen to check if the above hypothesis is correct?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  That was indeed the problem!  Ultimately I want to feed this image into an image classifier (this inverted color scheme is the necessary format).